# Haskell Stack is showing error "Could not find package id of package unix". How do I fix this error?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to run a Haskell script that uses the `unix` package using `stack` but it is showing error `Could not find package id of package unix`.

**Command Prompt:**

```
PS D:\Programming\Haskell> stack helpful_math.hs
Could not find package id of package unix
PS D:\Programming\Haskell> stack --version
Version 2.3.3, Git revision cb44d51bed48b723a5deb08c3348c0b3ccfc437e x86_64 hpack-0.33.0
PS D:\Programming\Haskell> stack ghc -- --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.4
```

The Haskell Script *helpful_math.hs* is:

```hs
#!stack
{- stack runghc
    --package split --package extra --package unix
-}
import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.List (sort, intercalate)
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Data.List.Extra (trim)
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Control.Monad.Extra (whileM)
import Control.Concurrent (myThreadId, throwTo)
import Control.Exception (UserInterrupt)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)
import System.Posix.Signals (Catch, installHandler, keyboardSignal)

promptString = "\n> "

prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt msg = do
  putStr (msg ++ promptString)
  hFlush stdout
  trim <$> getLine

exitOnCtrlC :: IO String
exitOnCtrlC = do
  tid <- myThreadId
  installHandler keyboardSignal (Catch (throwTo tid UserInterrupt)) Nothing

solve :: String -> String
solve = intercalate " + " . map show . sort . map readNum . splitOn "+"
  where readNum :: String -> Int
        readNum = read . trim

main = do
  putStrLn "Welcome to Helpful Math Program!"
  --putStrLn "Press Ctrl-C to exit at any point"
  whileM $ do
    input <- prompt "Enter sum expression"
    putStr "Answer is: "
    putStrLn . solve $ input
    line <- map toLower <$> prompt "Do you want to quit? (y | n)"
    return $ line != "y"
```

Comment: The `unix` package is not supported under Windows. You'll need to run this code on another machine or Linux VM. Probably Windows Subsystem for Linux will also do the trick. But it doesn't seem like you even use the package... probably best is just to remove the dependency, and use only platform-independent imports instead.

Comment: I think this package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/signal-0.1.0.4/docs/System-Signal.html#v:installHandler works on Windows

Comment: @leftaroundabout Actually I'm using the unix module System.Posix.Signals to detect Ctrl+C. Anyway thanks! It was a stupid mistake - I totally forgot that unix is not supported on Windows.

Comment: @Carsten Thanks! I'll look into this package. By the way, do you know of any better way to detect Ctrl + C in Haskell? (because that's what I was using System.Posix.Signals for here).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer myself. It was a stupid mistake - I forgot that unix is not supported on Windows. So the code won't run on Windows anyway.